# list index out of range error in simple code

Tags: python, compiler-errors, runtime-error

Here is my code and when i try to run it it displays the following error.
"List Index Out Of Range".
Please help me figuring it out and fixing this error. Also help me to understand why this happens?

```
t = int(input())
j = list(map(int,input().split()))
d=list(map(int,input().split()))
a =[]
b=[]
c=[]
for i in range(len(j)):
    l,h,m=a[0],b[0],c[0]
    if d[i]==1:
        a.append(j[i])
    if d[i]==2:
        b.append(j[i])
    if d[i]==3:
        c.append(j[i])
    a.sort()
    b.sort()
    c.sort()

if l+h>m:
    print(m)
if l+h<m:
    print(l+h)
```

Comment: In the first iteration of the `for` loop, what do you think the values of `a[0]`, `b[0]` and `c[0]` are?

Comment: You create 3 empty lists `a, b, c` and 2 lines below you try to access the first element `a[0],b[0],c[0]` of these 3 empty lists.

Answer (score 1):

**List Index Out Of Range** occurs whenever you try to call the unavailable index. In your code lists a,b,c are empty list but you are trying to call the first element(a[0], b[0], c[0])